# Save Bundle data to a file and read from file in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, byte, android-external-storage, parcel

I am dealing with web application that have webviews..
There are 3 or four webview..What I need is I wanna restore those webviews from previous stats after user killed the application..
I could save webview state like,

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();    
WebView.saveState(Bundle);
```

These are my requirments..

1. save each bundle data to a external storage location (custome created folder)
   **seperately** as parcel or bytes or whatever format...
2. read saved data **seperately** and convert to bundle then restore webviews when user
   starts the application

I dug in internet and i got this,

1. for saving bundles data seperately in cache folder-->"webstack" folder ,

   public void save(){
   File stackpath = new File(getContext().getExternalCacheDir(), "webstack"+unique_tab_id);

   ```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    WebBackForwardList stacks = saveState(bundle);

    if(stacks!=null&&stacks.getSize()>0) {
        Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
        parcel.setDataPosition(0);
        bundle.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
        byte[] bytes = parcel.marshall();
        parcel.recycle();
       ...//save Byte Array Data to file
    } else {
        stackpath.delete();
    }
   ```

}

2. this is for reading saved data and resore the bundles seperately,

   public void boolean restore(){
   File stackpath = new File(getContext().getExternalCacheDir(), "webstack"+unique_tab_id);

   ```
    if(stackpath.exists()) {
        Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
        byte[] data = ...//read file as Byte Array
        parcel.unmarshall(data, 0, data.length); 
        parcel.setDataPosition(0);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.readFromParcel(parcel);
        parcel.recycle();

        WebBackForwardList stacks = restoreState(bundle);

        if(stacks!=null && stacks.getSize()>0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
   ```

   }

But this not working..I cant see any forder named "webstack" in cache directory and no saved data in it..
furthermore I have an idea to save webview states as visited url list in aqulite data base..but its not the appropriate way to do this..even its a mess..

Pls help me ..
sorry for my bad english..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

For bundle i recommend to convert bundle first to HashMap<String,*> then You can store it to a file.
Read process similary You need to parse file to HashMap and set the keyvalue pairs to new bundle.
Bundle is binary format, can contains parcellable objects and another bundles, therefore serialization and deserialization out of app can not be error free.
Also note that bundle can have diferrent versions and therefore can not be transferrable from one application to another.